# How to get Windows Server 2008 R2 to skip 'Error' print job and try others

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-printer

I have a network printer installed on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.  To be clear, the driver is installed on the Windows machine and configured to connect to the printer via port 9100.  An application running on the machine prints to this printer, and it usually works.

Occasionally, a print job does not "work".. its status in the print queue is shown as "Error" and no other jobs are able to print on the printer either.  Usually nothing is found wrong with the printer.. it is online and ready to print, however Windows waits forever and the only way to get things going again is for an admin to cancel the problem job(s) and try them again.

But today, deleting the job was not enough, it was necessary to restart the Windows machine as well.  Once restarted, printing was fine without touching the printer.

I do not know what causes these problem jobs to come up in the first place.. but is there any way to get Windows to give up on them and move onto other jobs without human intervention?  It seems as if Windows is either not retrying, or retrying endlessly a job that will never work.  Either way, it's not ideal...

Thanks

Comment: How about restarting the print service?

Comment: Next time, I'll try that.. probably that would have been sufficient rather than rebooting the machine.  But other printers served by the same machine were working fine (from the same application).  But really our issue is how to prevent this "stuckness" from occurring.

Comment: Can it be traced to just that printer, or other printers as well?

Comment: Well.. this machine serves 2 printers.. one is a Datamax, the other a Sato.. different driver.. and in recent memory, I've only seen this problem come up on the Sato.  But the other printer is more likely to be on-connected-and-ready at all times therefore less likely to have a job fail.  So my first suspicion was that the problem is failure to recover from a legit error.. not a random spooler error.  But then, on another print server which serves 3 identical Konica/Minolta lasers, which are office printers and always on, sometimes the queue will jam on one of them for no explicable reason.